# Hyperledger Fabric setup

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I would like to setup Hyperledger Fabric on an Ubuntu machine with docker (docker-compose up). Is it possible to run the chaincode and nodejs code from another system (Mac system), as I already have Go and nodejs ready on the Mac.

Please help me with this query.

Answer (score 2):

you can use same environment in different systems. This is the main reason to choose docker and docker-compose.

Just follow [steps](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). Please confirm the version of tools.

To run on another system, you only have to simply build the image of your current hyperledger package on current system(Ubuntu). and use this image on another system(MAC).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can totally do that. Use this example: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/tree/master/examples/balance-transfer

Run docker-compose in your ubuntu machine. Update the app `config.json` and `/app/network-config.json` with ubuntu machine IP and make sure required ports are opened.

Run app on your mac.